# request notification permission for FCM token in React native for Android

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

As per the steps discuss [here](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage)

This is used to request notification permission for iOS device.

But do i need to add any code for Android ? such that user can get similar popup like iOS to get notification access request and user can allow or deny it.

```
async function requestUserPermission() {
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

  if (enabled) {
    console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
  }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to add any permissions for android. android will always gave you FCM token.

Comment: It's include in the doc: https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#android---requesting-permissions